# Create DEB package with jar files

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, deb

I want to create DEB packages with many small bash files and JAR files. This is the control file:

```
Source: agent
Section: unknown
Priority: optional
Maintainer: support@test.com
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
Homepage: www.test.com
#Vcs-Git: git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/agent.git
#Vcs-Browser: http://anonscm.debian.org/?p=collab-maint/agent.git;a=summary

Package: agent
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends}
Description: agent
override_dh_fixperms:
        dh_fixperms
        find debian -name '*.*' -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```

The tar file is 2.7 MB.
The produced DEB file is 2.1 KB
Looks like I'm missing some configuration. Can you help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet shows that you have mixed up a number of different files used in packaging.

`debian/control` provides the *meta* information about the package (e.g. which binary packages to build, how binary packages relate to each other; a human readable description what a binary package is about)

it does not contain any *build-specifics* (e.g. calling `javac` to compile java classes) nor information about the actual content (e.g. which files are to be included in the package).

the build-script (or *meta* build script, as it usually calls upstream's build system), is defined in `debian/rules`. incidentally this is the file that often has lines like `override_dh_fixperms:`, whereas these lines are *never* found in `debian/control`.

there are numerous ways how to define which files will be included in a package, the simplest being a list of files/directories (one per line) in `debian/install` (resp. `debian/PACKAGE.install`)

You *really* should read the [official documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian) about creating Debian packages before you do anything else.

Comment: Can you please give me some example?